# How do I verify the ID token with Firebase and Django Rest?

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication

I just can't wrap my head around how the authentication is done if I use Firebase auth and I wish to connect it to my django rest backend.

I use the `getIdTokenResult` provided by firebase as such:

```
 async login() {
            this.error = null;
            try {
                const response = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
                const token = await response.user.getIdTokenResult();

                /* 
                  No idea if this part below is correct 
                  Should I create a custom django view for this part?
                */

                 fetch("/account/firebase/", {
                     method: "POST",
                     headers: { 
                         "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                         "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": token.token,
                     },
                     body: JSON.stringify({ username: this.email, password: this.password }),
                 }).then((response) => response.json().then((data) => console.log(data)));
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        },
```

The only thing I find in the firebase docs is this lackluster two line snippet: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

where they write

```
decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
uid = decoded_token['uid']
# wtf, where does this go? 
# what do I do with this? Do I put it in a django View?
```

I found a guide here that connects django rest to firebase: https://www.oscaralsing.com/firebase-authentication-in-django/

But I still don't understand how its all tied together. When am I supposed to call this `FirebaseAuthentication`. Whenever I try to call the `login` function I just get a 403 `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

This whole `FirebaseAuthentication` class provided by the guide I linked to above - should I add that as a path on the backend?

```
path("firebase/", FirebaseAuthentication, name="api-firebase"),
```

Which is the api endpoint my frontend calls?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  Why are you bothering to send an ID token to your backend?  If you don't have a specific purpose for it, then there's no need.

Comment: I’m only using firebase for the auth, everything else is done through my Django and Postgres db. So when a user is verified and makes various requests on my website (saving posts, comments etc), I link the user to that post/comment or whatever action they are doing

Comment: OK, you have code to verify the token, and now you have a unique identifier for the user. I don't understand where you are stuck now - just use the uid wherever you see fit for your application.

Comment: Well I can’t use the uid to verify the user? How do I tell my backend that the user is authenticated? If they try to make a request I’ll just get 403 error. Somehow I need to communicate to my backend “hey here’s a firebase token, consider that as authentication for user X”

Comment: You can pass the token with every request, and validate it with every request before you act on the user's behalf.  The client is in control of that token, not your backend.  The token expires after 1 hour, so you should not persist it anywhere.  Let the client manage that.

Comment: Can you please guide me in the right direction on how to set up the backend for this? Like.. where does what go? Do you have any experience with django rest? I know that through Node and Express, I can just pass in the "jwt check" through middleware, eg `app.use(<check_jwt_function_here>);` but with django, I'm stuck